# Tokenizing Strings without Punctuation in Python and putting punctuation back subsequently

Tags: python, nlp, token, nltk, punctuation

After reading here for a while already, I have decided to make a post because I am not getting anywhere with my problem. Unfortunately, I am just a "finance guy" and need some help in coding with python. I have posts from social media platforms and would like to tokenize the sentences for NLP purposes (without punctuation), lemmatize the tokens and then reinstate the punctuation. For tokenizing and bringing back punctuation, I have used the following code so far:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

With the `join_punctuation` function, I wanted to put the punctuation back together correctly.

```
def join_punctuation(seq, characters='''!"#%&'()*+-.,/:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''):
    characters = set(characters)
    seq = iter(seq)
    current = next(seq)

    for nxt in seq:
        if nxt in characters:
            current += nxt
        else:
            yield current
            current = nxt
    yield current
```

So far, tokenizing works the way I want it to, as now I can lemmatize the words without being disturbed by punctuation. Here is an example:

```
text = "Today, (I) bought $GME and sold $TSLA!!"
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
print(tokens): "['Today', ',', '(', 'I', ')', 'bought', '$', 'GME', 'and', 'sold', '$', 'TSLA', '!', '!']"
```

But when I then want to put the punctuation back together, it works perfectly fine with punctuation behind words, but not if the punctuation occurs in front of the words (like `"( I)"` and `"$ GME"` instead of `"(I)"` and `"$GME"`):

```
newtext = " ".join(join_punctuation([w for w in tokens]))
print(newtext): "Today,( I) bought $ GME and sold $ TSLA!!"
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to reintroduce the punctuation? To me it looks like you're splitting up the original string, and then you want to put it back together again. Why do you need to put it back together?

Comment: @PaulM. Actually I wanted to:
1. Tokenize the text
2. Lemmatize the tokens: For this purpose, I used `word_tokenize` as for the lemmatizer to work, the must not include punctuation since then the lemmatizer package won't work; I excluded this part bc of better readability
3. Put Tokens with punctuation back together for further NLP processes, for which lemmatized words are needed as well as punctuation!

But nevermind, I solved the problem as I found out, that I can remove most of the punctuation. I only need marks like "!?" since those include polarity information.